# Can I login to RabbitMQ with vhost user

Tags: rabbitmq

I set 2 user in rabbitmq `superuser` and `user1`

And I visit `http://127.0.0.1:15672/`  , `superuser` can login
but `user1` login failed
Is it normal?? Can `user1` login or only administrator can login  ??

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`superuser` can login because is an `administrator` but he can't add/remove exchanges/queues etc because does not have access to any virtual-host.

`user1` can't access because does not have any tag. You can define an user and the add the permissions/rights.

> Can user1 login or only administrator can login ??

No, there are different kind of users, I report the help:

```
Comma-separated list of tags to apply to the user. Currently supported by the management plugin:

management
    User can access the management plugin 
policymaker
    User can access the management plugin and manage policies and parameters for the vhosts they have access to. 
monitoring
    User can access the management plugin and see all connections and channels as well as node-related information. 
administrator
    User can do everything monitoring can do, manage users, vhosts and permissions, close other user's connections, and manage policies and parameters for all vhosts. 

Note that you can set any tag here; the links for the above four tags are just for convenience.
```

hope it helps